# Tortoise SVN causing password lockout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Where I work, the SVN sever logins are tied to our Outlook accounts. Recently, I had to change my password as part of the security policy. Now, using TortoiseSVN is causing my account to be locked. My assumption, though not proven, is that it is attempting multiple logins with the pre-changed password.

I've tried clearing the cache from all of my saved data but the problem persists. I get a single successful login using my new password followed thereafter by request to once again enter my password - but this time I'm locked out.

```
[Edit] To be more clear on on reproducing the issue; 
1. Have the IT dept unlock my account
2. Choose TortoiseSVN repro-browser from a folder
- I successfully log into repro-browser and can see the file structure
3. Click on another folder
- Request for password re-appears
- Before attempting to enter another password, my account is verified
as locked by IT.
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

SteveJ

Comment: Do you have non-ASCII characters in the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue, I was able to get going again using the following steps.

1. Remove credentials stored in Window's; [Removing Windows Credentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/remove-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials)
2. Manually remove the authentication folder (As suggested by bahrep - thanks)

I'm not certain that step 2 was necessary, since I had used the 'clear authentication' option from TortoiseSVN settings - but I can't rule it out at this point either.

In case the links are broken, here is the general approach (Win-7);

1. Control panel, User Accounts, Manage Credentials
2. Click vault containing suspect credentials
3. Remove credentials
4. Remove the entire 'auth' folder at; %APPDATA%\Subversion\ **auth**\

Hope somebody finds it helpful......

SteveJ

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've already cleared authentication cache credentials: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-dia-saved-data

- Non-ASCII passwords may not work with Basic Windows authentication. If you are currently using VisualSVN Server, I can say that the capability to use such passwords was introduced in version 3.5.0 only and was not available in prior versions. Note that Integrated Windows Authentication never had any problems with passwords.
- Your IT dept have to analyze the logs and check whether the requests originate from other computers. There is a chance that there is some service configured with your user account's username and password and it's causing the lock out.

  I personally saw a case when a user complained about his AD account lock outs after he changed the password. The root cause was some build machine that was configured to use his username and password when authenticating to SVN server. It was a mystery for him who and how added his credentials to the build machine's configuration.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response - I'll create a ticket for IT to look at the logs. Nonetheless, doesn't it seem inconsistent that it could be another machine since I can reproduce it at-will on my machine and it otherwise doesn't occur? I've cleared the cache multiple times as per the given instructions. Are you aware of where the cache is stored? Perhaps I could delete it manually.

Comment: @SteveJ what about special or non-ASCII characters in the password? The cache is stored in "%APPDATA%/Subversion/auth/". Read https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/netmodel/#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds

Comment: thanks, I wish it were that -- the password is all alpha numeric.